# How can I count users in a month that were not present in the month before?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, psql

I am trying to count unique users on a monthly basis that were not present in the previous month. So if a user has a record for January and then another one for February, then I would only count January for that user.

```
user_id    time
a1         1/2/17
a1         2/10/17
a2         2/18/17
a4         2/5/17
a5         3/25/17
```

My results should look like this

```
Month   User Count
January     1
February    2
March       1
```

Comment: "So if a user has a record for January and then another one for February, then I would only count January for that user." do you mean you would only count February?

Comment: He would like to count only for the first time...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with BigQuery, but here's how I would solve the problem using TSQL. I imagine that you'd be able to use similar logic in BigQuery.

1). Order the data by user_id first, and then time. In TSQL, you can accomplish this with the following and store it in a common table expression, which you will query in the step after this.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY [time]) AS rn,*
from    dbo.employees
)
```

2). Next query for only the rows with rn = 1 (the first occurrence for a particular user) and group by the month.

```
select    DATENAME(month, [time]) AS [Month], count(*) AS user_count 
from      cte
where     rn = 1    
group by  DATENAME(month, [time])
```

This is assuming that 2017 is the only year you're dealing with. If you're dealing with more than one year, you probably want step #2 to look something like this:

```
select    year([time]) as [year],  DATENAME(month, [time]) AS [month], 
          count(*) AS user_count 
from      cte
where     rn = 1    
group by  year([time]), DATENAME(month, [time])
```

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate by the user id and the month.  Then use `lag()` to see if the user was present in the previous month:

```
with du as (
      select date_trunc(time, month) as yyyymm, user_id
      from t
      group by date_trunc(time, month)
     )
select yyyymm, count(*)
from (select du.*,
             lag(yyyymm) over (partition by user_id order by yyyymm) as prev_yyyymm
      from du
     ) du
where prev_yyyymm is not null or
      prev_yyyymm < date_add(yyyymm, interval 1 month)
group by yyyymm;
```

Note:  This uses the `date` functions, but similar functions exist for `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood question is - to exclude user to be counted in given month only if same user presented in previous month. But if same user present in few months before given, but not in previous  - user should be counted.

If this is correct - Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT Year, Month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS User_Count
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    DATE_DIFF(time, LAG(time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time), MONTH) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%x', time), MONTH) AS time, 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%x', time)) AS Year, 
      FORMAT_DATE('%B', PARSE_DATE('%x', time)) AS Month
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
  )
)
WHERE IFNULL(flag, 0) <> 1
GROUP BY Year, Month, time
ORDER BY time
```

you can test / play with above using below example with dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 'a1' AS user_id, '1/2/17' AS time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a1', '2/10/17' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a2', '2/18/17' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a4', '2/5/17' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a5', '3/25/17' 
)
SELECT Year, Month, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS User_Count
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    DATE_DIFF(time, LAG(time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time), MONTH) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      user_id,
      DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%x', time), MONTH) AS time, 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%x', time)) AS Year, 
      FORMAT_DATE('%B', PARSE_DATE('%x', time)) AS Month
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
  )
)
WHERE IFNULL(flag, 0) <> 1
GROUP BY Year, Month, time
ORDER BY time
```

The output is

```sql
Year    Month       User_Count   
2017    January     1    
2017    February    2    
2017    March       1
```

Comment: I dont think this is what the OP wants. Basically wants to count the user the first time it appears in a month and never count it again.

Comment: in following statement `were not present in the previous month` note singular for `month`. not `months` but `month`. Anyway -  let's leave it up to OP to clarify! :o)

Comment: Agree let's do that. Not sure why I offered my 2 cents-am not even rich ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.d,
    count(DISTINCT t1.user_id)
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time) AS d,
        --EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time)-1 AS d2,
        user_id
    FROM nbitra.tmp
) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time) AS d,
        user_id
    FROM nbitra.tmp
) t2
    ON t1.d = t2.d+1
WHERE 
(
    t1.user_id <> t2.user_id --User is in previous month
    OR t2.user_id IS NULL --To handle january, since there is no previous month to compare to
)
GROUP BY t1.d;
```